# Different border-radius in different field. Is it a good practice?

Tags: website-design, css

Using different border-radius for different fields (e.g. textboxes, buttons, cards) to make the curves looks similar. Curves on the large field doesn't look similar to small fields.

[image]

Expected:

[image]

What's the best practice and proper solution?